# Android check GPS status in the Fragment

Tags: android, gps, fragment

I have tried this code but it is not working.It always return true even if gps is deactive.

```
private Boolean getGpsStatus() {
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to make the call as shown in your code , you need to add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:

Answer (score 0):

First give the needed permission:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

and then you can use this to get the status of the GPS:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Use as this, or encapsule it on method if you need or want

Comment: Thanks,
        I have tried the code but still it is not working same error always return true.

Comment: Can you edit your post, and paste your code, to see where are the problems?